# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build Exception using Chewie Controller

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a video playing on the screen using the code below. When I hit the fullscreen icon on the controllers, I get the exception **setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build**. The screen should go to fullscreen in the landscape when I hit the icon. It goes but then comes to portrait again (i.e. device orientation).

The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
Debug console says:

```
This MaterialControls widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: MaterialControls
dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#8836f], _ChewieControllerProvider]
state: _MaterialControlsState#84529
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: VideoApp
dirty
state: VideoAppState#8eaa6
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure>
Element.markNeedsBuild
State.setState
_MaterialControlsState._updateState
ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners
...
The VideoPlayerController sending notification was: VideoPlayerController#cc7a6(VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:11:43.069000, size: Size(640.0, 360.0), position: 0:00:03.609000, buffered: [DurationRange(start: 0:00:00.000000, end: 0:00:10.543000)], isPlaying: true, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null))
```

Here is the code which I am using currently.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

typedef void EndOfVideo();

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {

  final VideoAppState _videoAppState = VideoAppState();

  final String videoUrl;
  final EndOfVideo endOfVideo;
  final bool autoPlay;

  VideoApp({
    this.videoUrl,
    this.endOfVideo,
    this.autoPlay
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _videoAppState;

}

class VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {

  bool _eovReached = false;

  // bool wasLandscape = false;
  // bool leaveFullscreen = false;

  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  VoidCallback listener;

  VideoAppState() {
    listener = () {
      if(_videoPlayerController.value.initialized) {
        Duration duration = _videoPlayerController.value.duration;
        Duration position = _videoPlayerController.value.position;
        if (duration.inSeconds - position.inSeconds < 3) {
          if(!_eovReached) {
            _eovReached = true;
            widget.endOfVideo();
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  initialize(){    
    if(_videoPlayerController != null && _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
      _videoPlayerController.pause();
    }
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      widget.videoUrl
    ); 
    if(_chewieController != null) {
      _chewieController.dispose();
    }   
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      // uncomment line below to make video fullscreen when play button is hit
      // fullScreenByDefault : true,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,   
      ],
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: false,
      autoInitialize: false,      
    );  

    _videoPlayerController.addListener(listener);    
    _videoPlayerController.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {    
    super.initState();  
    try {  
      this.initialize();      
    }catch(e){}
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(VideoApp oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (this.mounted){
      if(oldWidget.videoUrl != widget.videoUrl) {
        try {  
          this.initialize();
        }catch(e){

        }
      }
    }
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {    
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {     
    if(widget.autoPlay) {
      _videoPlayerController.play();
    }
    return new Container(
      child: new Center(
        child: new Chewie(
          controller: _chewieController,
        )        
      ),
    );    
  }
}
```

My question is what could be causing this error and how to fix this. I also want to make the video player go fullscreen when the orientation of the device is landscapeleft or landscaperight.
Let me know if I should add anything else in here.
Thank you.

Edit:

I have fixed the exception. Thanks to Ibrahim Karahan! I need help with making the video player go full screen when the device is turned landscape. Thanks again.

Comment: Move `if(widget.autoPlay) { _videoPlayerController.play(); }` this code to initialize method, You shouldn't do that, just build your UI widget tree on build method.

Comment: @IbrahimKarahan Doing so does not throw an exception. But the video player still toggles from landscape to portrait.